# Are JSON Web Tokens (JWT) suitable for server to server authentication?

Tags: jwt

It seems to me that *JWT* were design for **web clients** to **interact** with **servers**.

So, let's say **Server2** wants to retrieve resources from **Server1** via REST API (which does also grant JWT tokens upon successful authentication).

One idea that pops in my mind is to pretend that **Server2** is a user. **Server2** could pretend to be a user by fulfilling a `/users/login` POST request with say, for instance, `email` and `password`. That would grant a JWT for the subsequent resources requests.

But that *feels* a bit like a hack.

Ideas, recommendations?

Comment: So, in this scenario, Server2 is a web client, you say?

Comment: If you control both servers, you could use something like OAuth2 for server-to-server auth.

Comment: No, Server2 would be a separated server in a constellation of micro-services.  Thanks for reading =)

Comment: Yes, but it's also a client to another server.

Comment: True, server2 would be a client in this case, just not a web-client (I suppose).

Comment: If both servers are in the same private network, you could just pass user id in a header or something (and handle authentication on the perimeter, API gateway or what-have-you)

Comment: That is unfortunately not the case, running free plan on Heroku :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233614/discussion-between-daniel-martinez-and-sergio-tulentsev).

Answer (score 0):

Server to server communication generally uses an openId connect method if you're using an authentication service of sorts.

Your best option without an authentication/identity service is using HMAC-256 to authenticate and sign your data packets.